# How to implement floating licenses in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, licensing

What would be a good way to restrict an ASP.NET web application to only serve a given ammount of concurrent users?

Some requirements are:

- Application requires login (no need to worry about anonymous users).
- Multiple servers support (farm / load balancing).
- An active user can be considered to be the same as an active session (not signed off or expired).
- Additional logins must be denied if the maximum number of concurrent users has been reached.
- Accountability is needed (administrators should be able to see who the active users are).
- Minimum overhead on each web request (especially avoiding costly trips to a database on each request).
- Total number of concurrent users should be kept correct even if a web server hangs, disconnects from network or has to be restarted.
- Additional servers are available to host services (e.g. application servers).

Comment: It looks like this is a copy and paste question from a requirement spec. Things like "Accountability is needed" and restricting the concurrent users are two totally different things. I think you should consider asking only the specific question here?

Comment: :) In fact I just typed this, I'm the guy that writes the specs. I mean that whatever method is applied should be transparent enough for the admins to see who the application thinks is logged in when the limit is reached.

Comment: Probably an HttpModule? You'll most likely need to implement this logic in the  `AuthenticateRequest` and `PostAuthenticateRequest` events. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Jim, that's the closest I think I'll get for an answer. To intercept the requests using an HttpModule and from there to feed some custom logic to keep track of active users in a distributed way.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a global variable (static) and hook up the logic in your Application_OnStart, Application_BeginRequest, or Page_Load events.  Check out this for more an example: http://dotnetperls.com/global-variables-aspnet

Comment: This solves part of the problem; it could allow tracking the active users on a server, but to track across a server farm, it seems a more elaborate implementation would be needed.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are correct.  Session state can be moved out of process and I was confusing session state with application state.  Application state is actually very volatile (changing web.config will cause your application state to be flushed for example) so a better approach would be to use some sort of offline storage, such as SQL server.  You would have to have some kind of out of process agent to manage that database storage so it's accessible by all servers in a server farm or web garden topology.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it seems a service would be required to aggregate the active users information across the server farm. I'd rather not use a database for that to prevent contention on the database server. It seems an in-memory list will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

To restrict the number of concurrent users  you should be able to use,

```
<system.web>
      <applicationPool maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU="12" maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU="0" requestQueueLimit="5000"/>
</system.web>
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2009/07/08/iis7-improving-asp-net-performance-concurrent-requests-while-on-integrated-mode.aspx

Comment: Thank you but that's concurrent requests, it doesn't support the concept of a user, so I don't think it can be used to implement a floating licensing model. I need to limit the quantity of users that can be logged on the web application, with active sessions.

Comment: Yeah right..i have not come across any way of achieving it thru configuration alone.. You should probably think of doing a custom implementation to keep track of current users thru login logic?

Comment: I agree; in this question I'm trying to find out what would be good approaches for that. Thanks.